# Python not finding interperter

Tags: python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I created a very simply hello world node in python.  Though I can not get rosrun to execute because the python script will not find the interpreter.  When I run whereis python the first path I get it /user/bin/python3.4m.  There are several more bin paths listed and I have tried them all.  Not sure why it wont find it.  See the whereis and code below

Code

```
    ! /user/bin/python3.4m
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String

def talker():
pub = rospy.Publisher('hello_pub',String,queue_size=10)
rospy.init_node('hello_world_publisher',anonymous=True)
r = rospy.Rate(10) #10hz

while not rospy.is_shutdown():
str = "hello world %S"%rospy.get_time()
rospy.login(str)
pub.publish(str)
r.sleep()

if__name__=='__main__':
try:
talker()
except rospy.ROSInterruptException:pass
```

whereis

```
! /user/bin/python3.4m
import rospy
from std_msgs.msg import String

def talker():
pub = rospy.Publisher('hello_pub',String,queue_size=10)
rospy.init_node('hello_world_publisher',anonymous=True)
r = rospy.Rate(10) #10hz

while not rospy.is_shutdown():
str = "hello world %S"%rospy.get_time()
rospy.login(str)
pub.publish(str)
r.sleep()

if__name__=='__main__':
try:
talker()
except rospy.ROSInterruptException:pass
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223664/python-not-finding-interperter/) by [AgentNoise](https://answers.ros.org/users/25395/agentnoise/) on ROS Answers with karma: 38 on 2016-01-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

On most standard Linux/Mac/POSIX systems, python will be in `/usr/bin` (no `e`).

The scripts you've posted are also missing the leading `#` which informs the OS that the first line defines the interpreter to be used. Try using this as the first line of your program instead:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3.4m
```

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-01-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AgentNoise](https://answers.ros.org/users/25395/agentnoise/) on 2016-01-07**:
Oh, that was so obvious. Need to pay more attention.  Thank you.